# How authenticate a facebook user secure via javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need an unique id code of facebook user which is always the same, so i can save it on my websites database together with FB userID for further user login via facebook.
Unfortunately the authResponse contains only temporarly ids:

```
authResponse: {
   accessToken: '...', // expire
   expiresIn:'...',
   signedRequest:'...', // expire
   userID:'...'
}
```

I can't login a user only with FB userID... it would be too unsecure because i have to send the authResponse information via javascript to php. (PHP SDK don't work on my webspace [no root access]).

Is there any solution? Or maybe an other way to login/authenticate a facebook user into my website without using PHP SDK?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT :**
After submitting my question i found this similar post: [How to securely authorize a user via Facebook's Javascript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186146/how-to-securely-authorize-a-user-via-facebooks-javascript-sdk)

The questioner mentioned a way to authenticate the user in the followed step via encrypted information which is given from facebook via cookie.
I will try now to decrypt this cookie information like i did in "registration via facebook" part. With my appID and securityID.

Comment: "PHP SDK don't work on my webspace [no root access]" --- why do you think root is necessary for FB PHP SDK?

Comment: oh sry for misunderstanding... i was testing PHP SDK on my website and a php error appears saying: "Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension". And to install this extension i need root access :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to authenticate a facebook user via the encrypted cookie information works fine:

Here the code:

```
// PHP script which get visitor's FB ID over $_GET['fbid'] (for example through ajax or javascript redirect)
if(isset($_GET['fbid'])) {
    define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'YOUR APP ID');
    define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'YOUR SECRET ID');

    function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
        list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

        // decode the data
        $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
        $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

        if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
                error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
                return null;
        }

        // check sig
        $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
        if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
            error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
            return null;
        }

        return $data;
    }

    function base64_url_decode($input) {
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
    }

    // Check if Facebooks cookie is set
    if(isset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . FACEBOOK_APP_ID])) {
        $response = parse_signed_request($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . FACEBOOK_APP_ID], FACEBOOK_SECRET);

        // Check if userID sent by visitor is the same like decrypted userID given from cookie
        if($response['user_id'] == $_GET['fbid']) {
            // Login script here
            echo "Successfully authenticated!";
        } else {
            // userID sent by visitor is modified
            echo "Please don't use others FB ID!";
        }
    } else {
        // Facebook cookie is not set
        echo "Please allow cookies!";
    }

}
```