# How do I use a Facebook signed_request in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-javascript-sdk, asp.net-mvc-5, facebook-login

I'm using Facebook as a login provider for my web application (ASP.NET MVC).

My login works similar to another StackOverflow post [How to securely authorize a user via Facebook's Javascript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186146/how-to-securely-authorize-a-user-via-facebooks-javascript-sdk). I also share the user's concerns.

## The flow for my login is as Follows:

### 1. The user presses the login button.

[image: Log in with Facebook]

### 2. The user must accept the app.

[image: Accepting the app]

### 3. A javascript callback retrieves the response.

```
var authResponse = response.authResponse;
```

Object returned:

```
{
    accessToken: "...",
    expiresIn: 1234,
    signedRequest: "...",
    userID: "123456789"
}
```

I've heard that I can used the `signed_request` to validate the user's request, but *all the examples online are for PHP*. **How do I do this in .NET?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the **signed_request** can be used to verify that an incoming login request is genuine. If you're logging in a user with Javascript (via [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), for example) you can use the signed_request to ensure that the data isn't false.

According to [Parsing the Signed Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games), there are 3 major steps, however I'll be a little more specific.

1. Take the signed_request string and split it into two strings. There is a period character (full stop) which is a [delimiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter).

   - The first part of the string (the signature) is a hash of the second part.
   - The second part contains some information about the user and the request (user ID, timestamp).
2. The strings are in [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), but cannot be decoded straight away.

   - They are [Base64-URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) which means that `+` and `/` characters have been replaced with URL-friendly `-` and `_` characters. Replace `-` characters with `+` and `_` characters with `/`.
   - The strings may not be fully Base64 padded. Base64 strings should be divisible by 4; pad the strings out as necessary.
3. Hash the signature using [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) (SHA256) using your app secret as the key and compare the result to the signature that was provided.

   - Use the .NET class [HMACSHA256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

### 1. Split and decode

#### Code

```
string response = ""; // the signed_request

string[] split = response.Split('.');

string signatureRaw = FixBase64String(split[0]);
string dataRaw = FixBase64String(split[1]);

// the decoded signature
byte[] signature = Convert.FromBase64String(signatureRaw);

byte[] dataBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(dataRaw);

// JSON object
string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBuffer);
```

#### FixBase64String()

```
static string FixBase64String(string str)
{
    string result = str;

    while (result.Length % 4 != 0)
    {
        result = result.PadRight(result.Length + 1, '=');
    }

    result = result.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");

    return result;
}
```

### 2. Compare the hashes

```
byte[] appSecretBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my_app_secret_here");

HMAC hmac = new HMACSHA256(appSecretBytes);

byte[] expectedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataRaw));

bool areEqual = expectedHash.SequenceEqual(signature);
```

**If `areEqual` is `true` then you can be sure that the signed request is valid** and has not been tampered with (assuming your app secret is secure).

Remember to keep your app secret secure, otherwise malicious users can do bad things.

Comment: This code has an error. It is incorrectly computing the `expectedHash`, and so the final `areEqual` comparison will fail. This line `byte[] expectedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataRaw));` needs to be changed to `byte[] expectedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(split[1]));`.

Comment: @Rowan - I am working on the "Workplace of Facebook". In workplace also, we will have the App. I am able to get the signed_request when the Workplace app is uninstalled. I can decode the payload using your method to get the json object but I am not able to validate the signature.

Answer (score 5):

To compile Rowan's answer into its final code:

```
public static string DecodeSignedRequest(string signed_request)
{
    try
    {
        if (signed_request.Contains("."))
        {
            string[] split = signed_request.Split('.');

            string signatureRaw = FixBase64String(split[0]);
            string dataRaw = FixBase64String(split[1]);

            // the decoded signature
            byte[] signature = Convert.FromBase64String(signatureRaw);

            byte[] dataBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(dataRaw);

            // JSON object
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBuffer);

            byte[] appSecretBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(app_secret);
            System.Security.Cryptography.HMAC hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(appSecretBytes);
            byte[] expectedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(split[1]));
            if (expectedHash.SequenceEqual(signature))
            {
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // error
    }
    return "";
}

private static string FixBase64String(string str)
{
    while (str.Length % 4 != 0)
    {
        str = str.PadRight(str.Length + 1, '=');
    }
    return str.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");
}
```

Thanks Rowan!