# Facebook PHP SDK usage stand alone - how do the Facebook sessions/cookies work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm utilizing the Facebook PHP SDK on its own. I do not want to use the JS SDK at all.

Because getUser(); from the SDK can return a user id even if the user is not logged in, I have opted for using a try/catch statement to check if the user is logged in.

```
    try
{
    $me = $CI->facebook->api('/me');
    $CI->our_fb['is_fb']='YES';
    echo "hello";
}
    catch(FacebookApiException $e) 
{               
    echo "catch";
}
```

This statement is included in the global include file of all of my files (for simplicity).

So, depending on the situation, I generate a Facebook login URL. The expected functionality is that the user logins to Facebook, authorises the app, is returned to the redirect URI set in the login URL at which point the try statement will execute, and $CI->our_fb['is_fb'] will be set.

This is however not happening.

- If the user is already logged into Facebook and the app is authorised, it works perfectly. SUCCESS
- If the user is not logged into Facebook, once redirected the variable is not set. FAILURE
- If the user is logged in but the app is NOT authorised after redirect the variable is not set. FAILURE.

In the latter two cases if you simply refresh the page, the variable is set - SUCCESS. Refreshing the page is however unnecessary/pointless extra effort.

My problem is that if you need to login to FB/or authorise the app e.g the first time you login with FB, you have an additional unneeded refresh, and I don't know why.

I suspect it is something to do with the cookie/session? Which saves the access token that I assume is returned/passed to the SDK automatically not being set at the same time?

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: When you say "the variable is not set", are you also seeing `"catch"`?  In other words, is the exception being thrown?

Comment: Yes. The exception is being thrown. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: Have you examined the exception to see what it is, exactly?  e.g. `echo print_r($e, true);` in the catch block?

Comment: Yes - the exception is "OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." hence my belief it is something to do with how the cookie/session is set by facebook. Apologies once again :P/Thanks

Comment: Just curious: are you saying that you can get the user_id when the user is not logged in (your 3rd para)? Based on what I have seen, it is not possible. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: Ethan, I am not trying to get the user id under any circumstances, I am simply trying to do an api call to /me. In the second and third cases however an exception is caught on redirect.. suggesting that the cookie/session that should allow a successful api call is not being set in those cases..

Comment: Can you include your implementation for how you add the login url?

Comment: "If the user is not logged into facebook, once redirected the variable is not set. FAILURE" - How is it possible that they would be redirected from a facebook login url, but NOT be logged in to facebook?

Comment: They are logged into Facebook, but there is a failure in that the PHP SDK doesn't have an access token set, and thus the api queries are failing..

Comment: Right then - this is moving towards an answer :) Thanks.
So getLoginUrl() generates a link, on authorisation the user is redirected to the redirect_uri passed as a parameter. A code and state is passed in the URL. Now, sometimes (case 1) everything works, other times it does not. If you could post an answer explaining how to properly get said token with the SDK and why sometimes you don't need to, then I will mark your answer as correct, and give you a massive hug.

Comment: I have not worked with PHP but with python, server-side. Having said that, my understanding says that only in case 1, you should get the code and state, passed via the redirect_uri that you provided. In the other 2 cases, you should get only error/error_reason/error_description and state. Not sure how much this information helps you, but this is the foundation. If this is also your expectation, then I may be able to help you further.

Comment: OK. I am going to look into the code more tomorrow. COuld you possibly explain why you said in a (apparently deleted) previous comment that you believe my views on the workings of the PHP SDK to be a 'beginners' view? I have yet to find anything in the code to suggest the PHP SDK is NOT designed to handle everything for you..

Comment: @ThomasClowes PHP SDK is not handling situations when for example you've authorized application. Remove it and refresh the page. You have the user_id because it was saved in the session. But if you query the graph you'll get an error because the access token is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having an **app on facebook (tab or canvas)**. PHP SDK only get the User ID on initial loading of a page because a `signed_request` is sent with the request to your app.

But, when the app refreshes, the signed_request is lost (as it's facebook who send it).

So, in this case, you can append the `signed_request` to every URLs your use in your app - but that's really not optimal as the `signed_request` won't be regenarated - neither refreshed.

Your only real option is to rely on the JS SDK to set cookie correctly and allow `getUser` to work as expected. This is required because you're considered as a third-party app in Facebook (being in an iframe) and most browser will block you from setting cookies - so you need a work around handled by the JS SDK for you. You can search for `cross-domain cookies` or `third-party cookie` for explanation about the workarounds, but these workaround only work via JS scripting and iframe management.

Also, be sure to setup the JS SDK correctly: [channel file](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#channel), [cookie allowed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/), and send P3P headers (for IE).

You can also check this related question: [A proper approach to FB auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351235/a-proper-approach-to-fb-auth)

**About website**, the same mostly stays (but you have no `signed_request`). At this point, seriously consider using the JS SDK as it's way easier. Or else, you can make sure your app flow follow these guidelines: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/

Comment: I am referring to the implementation of login functionality on an external website, not an app tab/canvas..

Comment: Then you just have no `signed_request`. Sent for free, but the same idea mostly stay, use JS SDK it's way easier. If you want to only use PHP, than make sure your flow is implemented as follow: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/

Comment: I am not interested in what is easier :) I am interested in using PHP alone. Sadly, this does not answer the question as to how the Facebook PHP SDK works with sessions/cookies, and as such why it is not working in the two outlined situations..

Comment: I gaved you a lot of reference to help you un-stuck your trouble. If you need more, than you'll need to add code sample.

Comment: I'm not asking for help with specific code, rather as to how the Facebook PHP SDK works with cookies and sessions. You have linked to information about the Javascript SDK and the architecture of facebook logins, neither of which are relevant to the question... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I am seeing this is, you are trying to avoid that refresh if the user is not logged in and precedes to log in after the page has initially loaded.
So what you can do is make an ajax request to another page on your site, say for example id.php, which just loads the php sdk and echo $userid; and then you can grab the user id after login without the refresh.

Comment: This is a way around it, but from my investigations to make it work requires the same page be refreshed (I dont know why) + this is a fix, not an explanation of why.. Im really looking for an explanation of why/how the PHP SDK works with FB. Thanks

Comment: Ok so I am understanding a bit better now, you are having to do an additional (totally unnecessary) refresh additional to the redirect (which technically is a refresh), so yes I seems like the session access token is being saved but not passed to the facebook object in the first refresh it needs the second, to pass it, which is weird. on the redirect is there a ?code= trailing the redirect url, you could just write your own method of getting the access token from that avoiding the second redirect http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-for-desktop/, that way you get control

Answer (score 0):

Basically the cookie is used to save the signed request and session is used to save 'state', 'code', 'access_token', 'user_id'. If the above are present PHP SDK uses them, no matter if they are valid or not.

I think your problem lies in the CODE sent by facebook. Specifically these lines in base_facebook.php:

```
if ($code && $code != $this->getPersistentData('code')) {
  $access_token = $this->getAccessTokenFromCode($code);
```

...

```
protected function getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $redirect_uri = null) {
if (empty($code)) {
  return false;
}

if ($redirect_uri === null) {
  $redirect_uri = $this->getCurrentUrl();
}
...
```

Because CODE is issued for specific url sometimes there is such situation: Visitor arrives on www.example.com. He givies permissions and is redirected to example.com/login. But the code is not valid there, so the getUserAccessToken returns false. When you refresh the page you get same urls and everything's fine.

You're on the right track of not using getUser() because as I wrote above it's taken from the session if available.

Comment: With the PHP SDK there is no signed request.. right? So that is only relevant if integrating with the JS SDK? I see what you are saying - this is the closest to an answer. Perhaps you could clarify? The code is issued for a specific page hence why a refresh on the same page works. It gets an access token based on the code returned, then on consecutive pages we dont have a code and the access token has to be gotten through getUser() and the saved session I believe. So we get this access token and try and query the API. If it catches an exception, the access token is invalid and we shuld relgin?

Comment: The signed request is available when your app loads from within facebook. 
You should keep using getUser() just don't rely on it. Get accces token with the $facebook->getAccessToken() method and query the graph. If there is an error redirect to facebook permission dialog. You should get new code and reset all the session data by using getUser() after the redirect.

Comment: This answer has been closest to answering the question. I am looking into it further and will follow up after the weekend before marking it as a complete and correct answer.