# Show FB Login, only if not logged in before for the current site

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Question is similar to 
[A proper approach to FB auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351235/a-proper-approach-to-fb-auth)

However i only want client side code.

Conditions
1. User may not be logged into FB. In this case user "has to" login to FB and effectively my App.
   Show FB Login button.
2. User is already logged into FB. Not logged into my App.
   Show FB Login button.
3. User is logged into Fb and my app.
   Show App. No FB login button

Problem : if user is already logged into FB, FB.login results in error.

I need community help. I know its a simple logical problem, however I am circling around the solution for hours now.

My code

```
    <div id="auth-loggedout" onclick="fbLogin()">
    <span class="buttonText">Login with Facebook</span>
    </div>


<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId : 'APP ID',   // App ID from the app dashboar
        channelUrl  : '/channel.html',  // Channel file for x-domain comms
            status : true,    // Check Facebook Login status
         xfbml : true    // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // this check FB login status on initialization
           fbLogin();
};
        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
  var login="false";
  function fbLogin(){
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
              document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
              document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'block';
              login=true;
              getDataFromFBAndgetSessionToken();<= This also needs FB object
          } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
              // the user is logged in to Facebook,
              // but has not authenticated your app
              document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
              document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'none';
          } else {
              // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
              document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
              document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'none';
          }
      });

      if (login === 'false')
      {
          FB.login();
      }
    };

   function getDataFromFBAndgetSessionToken() {
     FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,username', function (response) {

        varAccessToken = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];

       userFirstName = response.first_name;

       var User = new classUser();
       User.set_access_token(varAccessToken);
       User.set_fb_user_id(response.id);
       User.set_first_name(userFirstName);
       User.set_last_name(response.last_name);
      User.set_user_name(response.username);

    });
 }

 // Load the SDK asynchronously
 (function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  </script>

<script>
```

Comment: _“Problem : if user is already logged into FB, FB.login results in error.”_ – that’s nonsense, `FB.login` will not generate an error just because it is called when a user is already logged in.

Comment: I get this error "FB.login() called when user is already connected.". So I would assume that there is cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (login === 'false')
{
     FB.login();
}
```

This part of code run directly when fbLogin is called, login will always be "false" since there is no loginstatus come back yet.

It should be placed inside the callback function of  FB.getLoginStatus and it will be called when you can the response of the login status

the following code will run FB.login if it find that the user didn't authorize or login

```
var login="false";
  function fbLogin(){
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
              document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
              document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'block';
              login=true;
              getDataFromFBAndgetSessionToken();<= This also needs FB object
          } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
              // the user is logged in to Facebook,
              // but has not authenticated your app
              document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
              document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'none';
          } else {
              // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
              document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
              document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'none';
          }
          if (login === 'false')
          {
              FB.login();
          }
      });


    };
```

Comment: I know login is your own variable. Your checking is run inside fbLogin(),  what I　mean is that the code should be run inside the callback of FB.getLoginStatus(), (e.g: after else { } ),  so that FB.login() will be called after you received the login response

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work always (I think so, still testing)  - if you like the following approach, please let me know.

```
 <script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     // init the FB JS SDK
      FB.init({
        appId   : 'appid',    // App ID from the app dashboard
        channelUrl  : '/channel.html',    // Channel file for x-domain comms
        status  : true,    // Check Facebook Login status
        xfbml   : true    // Look for social plugins on the page
      });

    fbApiInit = true;
   };
        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
   function fbLogin(){
      FB.login(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected' ) {
              document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
              document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'block';
              localStorage.setItem("setapplogin","true");
              getDataFromFBAndgetSessionToken();
          } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
              // the user is logged in to Facebook,
              // but has not authenticated your app
              document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
              document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'none';
          } else {
              // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
              document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
              document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'none';
          }
      });

};



// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  </script>

<script>

function checkFBLogin(callback){
   if(!window.fbApiInit) {
       setTimeout(function() {checkFBLogin(callback);}, 50);
    } else {
      var applogin = localStorage.getItem("login");
      if (applogin === "true")
      {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'block';
                getDataFromFBAndgetSessionToken();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'none';
                localStorage.setItem("login", "false");
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
      } else {
         document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

};

function getDataFromFBAndgetSessionToken() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,username', function (response) {

        if (!response || response.error) {
           document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
           document.getElementById('appcontainer').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            varAccessToken = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];

            userFirstName = response.first_name;

            var User = new classUser();
        User.set_access_token(varAccessToken);
        User.set_fb_user_id(response.id);
        User.set_first_name(userFirstName);
        User.set_last_name(response.last_name);
        User.set_user_name(response.username);

       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works consistently for me.

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      if (response.status == "connected") {
        //user conected
      } else if (response.status == "not_authorized") {
        //user has not autorized app
      } else if (response.status == "unknown") {
        //user is not logged in to facebook
      }
  });

  $("#fb-login-button").click(function () {
      FB.login($.proxy(function (response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {
             //User Authorized app
          } else {
             //User did not authorize app
          }
      }, this), {
          scope: '{permissions_list}'
      });
  });
```